# Как вернуть слитие или как убрать merge ненужных коммитов?

Tags: git

Имеются 2 ветки (dev и upstream)

Dev разрабатывается отдельно, и свои стили.
Upstream ветка базовая, которую изредка заливают в dev.

Случайно залил dev в upstream и запушил. В upstream'e висят коммиты dev ранние.
Как избавиться от этого merge?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можете жестко откатиться обратно git reset --hard <название комита>

Comment: Reset откатит изменения, которые были внесены позже, а там коммитов на месяц. При создании issue с upstream, upstream подает на каждое коммиты с dev, которые мне не нужны. Конечно было бы не плохо удалить ветку origin/upstream. И слить все issue в неё, но увы, некоторые коммиты были прям на upstream написаны.

Comment: @ratatuy, команда `$ git reset --hard хэш-коммита` переставит указатель «текущая ветка« (и состояние рабочего каталога) на указанный коммит. укажите тот, который **вам нужен**.

Comment: да, только он переставит, а последующие потеряются. Там ток придется cherry-pick делать. Нету функции типа merge-down. Было бы не плохо.

Comment: @ratatuy, если *rebase* подходит (ветка считается *неопубликованной*), то вам нужен *git rebase —interactive <merge commit - 1>* (там ещё ключ есть, чтобы не дербанить слияние на отдельные составляющие). Если же ветка *опубликованная*, то только руками делать фактически revert commit.